# How can I get notified when a new jailbreak or unlock is released?

Tags: jailbreak, unlock

I got borred about all the spam created by less or more famous iOS hackers. They simply create too much hype for nothing: tweets, rss feeds, facebook pages, all of the full of nonsense messages.

I do not want to spend my time reading fake news about new hacks and I'm looking for a way of subscribing only to real "news".

For a while I considered the Jailbreak Matrix to be a page I could monitor but it looks that it not updated in time and the page became too crowded by ads.

What information source do you recommend?

Comment: I myself use mostly [cazisoft](http://cazisoft.com/feed) on my gmail, but they also bring along some irrelevant news as well. Maybe just adding on it some filter for "jailbreaking" would be enough for you, Sorin, but I would like to see something more straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

iClarified reports on all the iOS jailbreaking/unlocking news that's relevant (along with a lot that's not entirely relevant) really quickly: http://www.iclarified.com/

Comment: Thanks, but the point was how to get only relevant stuff :D